# All property IDs became invalid - Automatically changed to tracking ID UA-0-0 instead

Tags: google-analytics

[image: Issue on GA]

Anyone getting the same issue too? I scoured the documentations and it seems it has no mention on this case. This thing happened overnight. Checked property changes and nothing alarming.

Comment: Yeah we are facing this as well in our project. The linking between firebase and ga is also broken, and on firebase projects its asking to enable google analytics again, and on GA, all the tracking ids have become invalid.

Comment: We were facing this as well. Just got fixed. Everything is working as expected.